# Откуда берется отступ сверху у левой боковой колонки?

Tags: html, css

Почему не срабатывает padding-top как надо?
Откуда берется лишний отступ у списка ссылок?

Как сделать меню в один уровень с картинкой справа?  [вот сайт](http://spbvikupavto.ru/vykup-inomarok/)

[image: Почему не срабатывает padding-top как надо. и откуда берется лишний отступ у списка]

Comment: "Почему не срабатывает padding-top как надо" а как надо? правильная формулировка вопроса - верный путь к успеху ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У колонки не задан `vertical-align`. По умолчанию он у вас `middle`. Сделайте его `top`.

```
#sidebar {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 5px 5px;
    width: 25%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top; /* Добавьте эту строку */
}
```